# compile code online for coding competitions

Tags: compilation, online-compilation

I want to conduct online coding competitions. For that I am developing a website. I have a webpage to take the code from user. Once the user has finished his coding, on submitting I want to send that code to some compiler to check the code. And I can check with the test cases if its compiled without errors. Is there any online compilers available for that. I mean, Is there any site to send my_code, test_cases, programming_languages to that and get back the results? Or should I use system commands to do this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling requires a fair amount of computation. You will have to consider how well your system will scale to user demand. Most online services would eventually charge a fee to cover their infrastructure costs (+ profit).

See ideone.com/sphere-engine

Depending on the scale, you may want to use system commands. I would suggest doing so until your project reach a certain maturity. You could also have a setup like Jenkins, were compilation work is dispatched to build nodes which can be added for increased demand.

Existing software like [PC<sup>2</sup>](http://www.ecs.csus.edu/pc2/) ask the hosts of the competition to provide the compilation server. However, the setup is local.